# How to emulate Windows network for `ntlm_auth`?

Tags: samba

I want to host a Squid proxy that demands NTLM auth `proxy-authenticate: NTLM`. (It's to a test server--I'm developing a HTTP client that needs to cope proxies demanding this protocol--it's popular in Windows offices).

Anyway, the Squid setup is all done. This question isn't about Squid. Squid delegates authentication to `ntlm_auth` per http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.HEAD/cfgman/auth_param.html .

> ntlm_auth - tool to allow external access to Winbind's NTLM authentication function

The problem is I don't have a Windows domain around. Is it possible to make Winbind (Samba)  act like a Windows domain for the sake of `ntlm_auth` ? I just want one account with a given username and password. Someone with these credentials should be to authenticate to the proxy, but not do anything else on my computer.

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

There are many of achieving the same, but following is the easy, best and fast way of doing this.

You can setup your own eBox server (Zentyal). Just following below link for step by step implementation

[Using eBox as Windows Primary Domain Controller](http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Pdc-howto#UsingeBoxasWindowsPrimaryDomainController)